# Aplicacion de java se congela de lo lenta que va al usar mysql remoto

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una app en java que utilizaba una bbdd en access que siempre recuperaba unos 6000 registros en una fraccion de tiempo imperceptible pero decidi alquilar un host con 1gb de ram ssd y desde esa misma aplicacion me conecto a el para hacer las mismas consultas.

Mi sorpresa es que el programa se queda congelado y tarda más de 20 minutos solo en sacar los datos necesarios (unos 250) para arrancar y es extremadamente lenta la conexion entre mi programa y la bbdd. Mi internet es 60 megas de bajada y 90 de subida y haciendo consultas desde phpmyadmin me tarda 0.0009 segundos por lo que el hosting no tiene problema.

En java uso la siguiente clase para conectarme a la bbdd y funciona perfectamente:

```
public Connection connectDB(){

    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mi_ip:3306/nombre_ddbb", "miusuario", "micontraseña");

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido cargar el controlador.", "Awsys", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    return conn;
}
```

Cada vez que se hace una consulta es así:

```
PreparedStatement sentencia = connectDB().prepareStatement(consulta);
```

¿A alguien le ha pasado lo mismo?

Comment: Dime el phpadmin lo ejecutas desde tu computador donde también ejecutas tu programa java? De lo contrario no podrías comparar si el phpadmin se ejecuta en el host remoto. . Deberias  probar con  las librerías del MySQL en lugar del JDBC o en todo caso verifica que estés utilizando el último driver.  Me parece que el phpadmin utiliza librerías MySQL no JDBC.

Comment: Estoy utilizando el ultimo driver de mysql connector y al phpmyadmin me conecto desde el mismo pc que tengo el programa en java. He hecho una clase a parte que devuelve una consulta con 250 datos y ha tardado milisegundos en mostrar el resultado, usando el mismo driver. ¿Alguna otra idea?:(

Comment: Puedes intentar actualizar el driver JDBC que estás usando? No se me ocurre otra cosa ya que dices que desde el phpadmin en la misma PC donde corre tu aplicación esto no es así. Por lo tanto, casi podemos descartar problemas en el servidor y/o en la red.

Comment: Me he descargado el ultimo desde la pagina de mysql..

Comment: ¿No te da ningún warning al lanzar la aplicación? Según yo el nombre del driver que debes utilizar es **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver** en lugar de **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

Comment: Si haces varias consultas asigna tu objeto **Connection** a una variable en lugar de llamar el método **connectDB()** cada vez